# AVR ISP not working, strange signal level

Tags: avr, atmel, isp

I can't read the chip ID of the ATMega16m1 MCU using a AVRISP mkII programmer.

The ISP pins are connected directly to the MCU, the reset line has a 10k pullup to Vcc (3.3V).

When measuring the ISP lines using a oscilloscope (see below), I saw that the the MISO line is stuck at ~1.68V which isn't right I believe. When I connect the programmer to a Arduino nano clone it works properly.

Does anyone have a clue what might be wrong?

[image: AVR ISP measurement]

Comment: What else is connected to the MCU? Consider providing a schematic. Have you tried programming the MCU without anything else connected?

Comment: Debugging questions need to be documented clearly with *all the details* of your setup. It's difficult enough to debug these things on a bench, without all information in the question it's like doing it blindfolded.

Comment: @JYelton: issue is solved, next question I'll post a schemetic :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the details of your resolution. It may help someone else with the same or similar issue!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is solved :)

I'd connected the programmer to the CLK/MISO/MOSI pins, but for the ATmega16m1 the ISP has to be done using CLK_A/MISO_A/MOSI_A.